# while importing .txt file in teradata iam getting invalid time stamp.Actually file contains time stamp data like 20180607123456000

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a `.txt` file contains time stamp column like 20180607093059000 and some other columns, but while importing into teradata SQL assistant getting invalid time stamp error. please help me the way
as I need to import file data into volatile and has to do minus operation between these file table and actual table.

Answer (score 2):

The default format for a timestamp is `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'`, you can apply `TO_TIMESTAMP`

```
To_Timestamp(ts, 'yyyymmddhhmissff3')
```

which results in a Timestamp(6)

To get Timestamp(3) you need to CAST using a FORMAT after adding the fractional period:

```
Cast(Substring(ts From 1 FOR 14) || '.' || Substring(ts From 15) AS TIMESTAMP(3) FORMAT 'yyyymmddhhmiss.s(3)')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply dnoeth .But problem here is while importing we are using the option import in teradata like below insert into table values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)..how can we apply cast for this case

Comment: @sra1: I don't think you can do this during import, only after in your Select.

Comment: I select import option-->select the above written query-->File Explored opens up-->I selected my file-->Then it displays error as 'Invalid time stamp'

Comment: @sra1: You need to import it into a Varchar column and then apply the cast during the select